# Count number of words used in an answer, following a question line

Tags: text-processing, awk

Example input:

```
Question1: What kind of cake do you like?
Anything with sprinkles
```

Example output:

```
Question1: What kind of cake do you like?
3 Anything with sprinkles
```

The only markers are the "Questionx: " and the "?". Answers always follow questions. This screams awk to me, (find /?$/) but I can't quite get the multi-line aspect to play nice with the word count ($NF). Other languages are available, like perl/python/php, etc. but I'm trying to avoid programming what I feel should be a simple one liner

Comment: Are questions multiline? Are answers multiline?

Comment: Single line answers and questions. I firgot that the answers can be blank - 0 word count for those. Questions need to be without a word count

Comment: Blank, meaning an empty line? Or the answer line is absent and you have consecutive questions?

Comment: Empty line for a blank answer, questions will be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pending the answer to my comment above:

```
awk '/^Question[0-9]+:.*\?$/ {print; next} {print NF, $0}'
```

or

```
awk '{printf "%s%s\n", (/^Question[0-9]+:.*\?$/ ? "" : NF " "), $0}'
```

Comment: The second one is the winner

Answer (score 0):

This will give the number of "words" in each question by itself:

```
awk '/^Question/ {if (NR > 0) print words; words=0} $0 !~ /^Question/ {words+=NF}' /path/to/input
```

To print questions and the number of words on each line as you describe:

```
awk '/^Question/ {print} $0 !~ /^Question/ {print NF, $0}' /path/to/input
```

To make each line's numerical prefix cumulative:

```
awk '/^Question/ {words=0; print} $0 !~ /^Question/ {words+=NF; print words, $0}' /path/to/input
```